# How to handle Legend-of-Zelda-esque magic items without aspect spamming?

Tags: magic-items, fate-core, equipment

I think that one of the reasons that Zelda is a good setting for Fate is because advancement is horizontal rather than vertical. In other words, instead of zero-sum increases to power level as in other games, Zelda is about using your tools in unique ways to solve the problems. I'm talking mostly about *aspects as permissions*, as far as translating that over to Fate:

- You have the Magic Hammer, therefore you can use blunt force to flatten enemies and stakes.
- You have the Hookshot, therefore you can grab things that would normally be out of reach.
- You have the Bow and Arrow, therefore you can attack enemies at range.
- Etc.

The problem I'm facing right now is that [aspect spamming is bad](http://ryanmacklin.com/2013/11/fate-misconceptions-and-aspect-spamming/). A campaign that is modeled specifically after Zelda universe would have about 10-20 magic items for the players to find in various dungeons, which means that by the end of a completed game, each character would have 3-6 additional item aspects taking up space on their sheets.

**So my question is**: How should I handle magical plot-relevant items that are acquired as the campaign goes on? If they are few-and-far-between and plot-relevant, is it okay for me to devote so many bonus aspects to them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Special equipment doesn't sound like an Aspect to me. Aspects are supposed to be double-edged: you can invoke them for a bonus, or they can be invoked/compelled against you to put you at a disadvantage. Most items in Zelda games aren't built with particular weaknesses, though there are exceptions -- the Iron Boots make you slow, the Zora Tunic in *Twilight Princess* makes you weak to fire and ice, and so on.

You might be able to think compels for your items too -- "You're tempted to fire an arrow, but the mighty winds swirling around would curve your shot at something you really don't want to hit!" -- but if you want your players to feel really awesome about their items most/all of the time, Aspects aren't the best choice.

[Stunts](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/building-stunts) are the typical domain of letting you do something uniquely awesome. Depending on how often you award these items, it might replace the point of refresh gained at a [major milestone](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/advancement-change#major-milestones), as if the player automatically spent that point on a new Stunt which is the item. You can also balance Stunts by determining how often they can be used for their effect -- there might be a mundane use that's unlimited to solve common obstacles, plus a more powerful effect limited to once per scene or session.

Finally, you can make your items into [Extras](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/creating-extra). Through the magic of Fate's Bronze Rule, your items can become "characters" of their own, letting you assign Aspects, Skills, and/or Stunts depending on what you want them to do. The benefits of doing this are:

- Your items are all the same -- If there are any recurring "themes" for how you want these items to work in the setting (the item can overcome these obstacles, the item consumes these ammo/points), you can make that part of all your Extras.
- Your items are all different -- Using Extras means you're not trying to pigeonhole them as Aspects, Skills, or Stunts when they might not all be similar enough to fit the same mold.

Answer (score 4):

I would make either make them Stunts/Extras or, as suggested in the linked article, note them as "narrative flavor" and leave it at that.  Specifically, the fact that you have the X thing allows you to do Y, and if you don't have X, you can't do Y, much like how you can't use your Shoot skill if you don't have a gun, even though "Has a gun" isn't an aspect.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is the difference between "Has a gun" and "Has the Legendary Cane of Somaria."
Can Extras be aspects? That might be redundant.

Comment: @Robert Extras can be aspects. Extras can be anything, really. "Extra" is pretty much Fate's word for "campaign-specific house rules." The main thing that differentiates them from campaign-specific house rules in other systems is that Fate has some clear guidelines on how to use the system's existing building blocks to make the specific house rules you need.